# Get list of selected value from array object in angular js

Tags: angularjs, json

I am new in angular js. I have one array object as

```
var data = [{ id:1, name: 'Adam', email: 'adam@email.com', age: 12},
            { id:2, name: 'Amalie', email: 'amalie@email.com', age: 12}];
```

Now, I want data as

```
var data_id = [{1},{2}];
```

So what should I have to get only id list from array object?

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Question has been updated.

The format you want the data in (`[{1},{2}]`) cannot be achieved. A javascript object has to have a key and a value. so, `{1}` is invalid.
But on the other hand if it's just the ids you want (`[1,2]`), see the mapping below and instead of returning `{id: item.id}`, just return `item.id`.

```
var data = [{ id:1, name: 'Adam', email: 'adam@email.com', age: 12},
            { id:2, name: 'Amalie', email: 'amalie@email.com', age: 12}];

// [{id: 1, {id: 2}}]
var data_id = data.map(function(item){
    return { id: item.id};
});

// [1, 2]
var data_id = data.map(function(item){
    return item.id;
});
```

If you're using ES6, you could simplify the code

```
var data_id = data.map(item => ({ id: item.id}));
```

You can use javascript `map` function to extract just the id.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, Objects are having `key` and `value` both.

```
var obj = {
  myKey: value,
}
```

You can try JavaScript [**array.map()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. It will return the array with the elements you want to access.

```js
var data = [{ id:1, name: 'Adam', email: 'adam@email.com', age: 12},
            { id:2, name: 'Amalie', email: 'amalie@email.com', age: 12}];
            
var result = data.map(function(item) {
  return item.id;
});

console.log(result);
```